# Working with Multiple forms in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a small application in MVC 4. I have 2 forms form1 and form2 in single view. When one form is posted I proceed to the next form where I redirect from view to a action method Employee in which I perform some task and then again from action method I return back to view, in the view I want to go for form2 without touching form1 how do I do that.
Below I will show sample of how my code looks like

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
//some task
resturn view();
}

public ActionResult Employee()
{
//some task
}
```

**View**

```
@html.BeginForm("Index","Show",FormMethod.Post,new {@name=form1})
{
//Shown something
}

@Html.Action("Employee","Show")


@html.BeginForm("Employee","Show",FormMethod.Post,new {@name=form2})
{
//Shown something
}
```

Comment: Please explain more...

Comment: Or better. I read your questions 3 times and didn't quite get what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Javascript that checks if any of the required values in form 1 is set. If so, set focus on whatever element you want in form 2. Here's an example:

The html forms:

```
<form id="one">
    <input type="text" id="requiredFormField" value="some value previously entered" />
</form>
<form id="two">
    <input type="text" id="form2text" />
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(setFocusIfForm1Completed());
function setFocusIfForm1Completed()
{
    var expectedValue = $("#requiredFormField").val();
    if(expectedValue.length > 0)
    {
        $("#form2text").focus();
    }
}
```

I should add that I assume that you fill in form 1, then you submit (do a POST request to the server) which does some work, and then returns the same view but with at least some required value from form 1 populated (otherwise, this solution breaks).